Is there really a Midrash that says that G-d originally intended on Yaakov and Eisav to be born as one child but then then split into separate twins?
I heard this on a Torah class but there was no source provided. Is there really a Midrash that says that G-d originally made Yaakov and Eisav as one person but then Hashem split them into two separate twins because Rivkah complained about the pains of pregnancy? If so, please provide the source.  Thanks!
